# ES6 - Browserify + babel + flot chart plugin

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, flot, babeljs

I am trying to use flot chart as a node dependency and use bable and browserify to bundle everything in my application.

I have a flot chart working fine by just using **import 'flot';**

I would also like to use the other types of charts flot can handle such as a pie chart.

The flot node_modules folder has jquery.flot, jquery.flot.pie, etc. jquery.flot is imported and bundled. However I can jquery.flot.pie is not. an import statement like import 'flot.pie' doesn't work either. I am also using gulp to build the app.

Anyone have any suggestions? I am relatively new to node babel, and browserify.

Here is my browserify setup in package.json

```
"browserify-shim": {
"bootstrap": {
  "depends": [
    "jquery:jQuery"
  ]
 }
},
"browserify-swap": {
"@packages": [
  "underscore"
],
"dist": {
  "underscore.js$": "lodash"
}
},
"browserify": {
"transform": [
  "babelify",
  [
    "hbsfy",
    {
      "extensions": [
        "hbs"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "browserify-swap",
  "browserify-shim"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this question by putting the reference to the flot.pie plugin in the package.json.

```
 browser": {
  "bootstrap": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
  "flot.pie":"./node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.pie"
},
```

Now I can use `import 'flot';` and import `'flot.pie';`